# On Android 11 Remote Bound Service binding fails when invoked from Client app after adding query

Tags: android, android-11, bindservice

I have exactly same issue.
[On Android 11 Remote Bound Service binding fails when invoked from Client app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691117/on-android-11-remote-bound-service-binding-fails-when-invoked-from-client-app)

I have added query as well as suggested by @CommonsWare. Even after adding query in client side, bindservice still returns false.

In Android 10, bindservice works fine but in Android 11 bindservice returns false.

Do I need to any additional modifications?

EDIT:
Server side I am getting the below error:
system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=de.esolutions.abc.absservice pkg=com.app.abc } U=10: not found